# Dynamically sized boost::asio::buffer

Tags: c++, dynamic, buffer, boost-asio

I'm reading from a `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` like this:

```
using boost::asio::ip::udp;

// ...

char recv_buf[128];
udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
size_t len = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), sender_endpoint);
```

Now, this works perfectly fine, but the maximum amount of characters that I am able to recieve is now 127. However I am facing a problem because I need to accept some data input of which the length can greatly vary (and is not of well-defined length with prefixed headers, for example). A solution to this would be a dynamically expanding buffer, like a vector. Is it possible to create a dynamically expanding `boost::asio::buffer` to accept (theoretical) infite amounts of input and store it in a container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDP datagram size does not vary all that greatly: it will never be greater than [65535](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure), leaving room for 65,527 bytes of data after the 8-byte header.

Comment: +1 You are totally right! Still I would be interested in a dynamic `boost::asio::buffer`, not because 64KiB is so huge, but a dynamic buffer often seems a lot more appropriate, and for reuse in TCP.

Comment: @nightcracker with TCP, asio calls the read handler when the buffer is full, so you can empty it and return to reading.

Answer (score 3):

Boost 1.66.0 added `dynamic_buffer` which can adapt a reference to `std::string` or `std::vector<CharType>`:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dynamic_buffer.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use smaller buffers, you can easily chain them together via the *BufferSequences concepts. For example, you can pass in a [MutableBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html)
 to accept data from a read(2) call or pass a [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) for a list of buffers that you are going to write(2) out. That said, I tend to recommend using a single buffer in each direction because it tends to simplify code (though that's not always possible).

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any provision for dynamic sizing.  And it makes sense that there would not be.  Think about what would have to happen:

- A single UDP datagram can only be received once, and at once, therefore:
- the buffer given to the low-level system call needs to be large enough for the largest valid message, so,
- for it to be efficient, the buffer must be allocated up-front by the caller.

So it does not make sense for there to be a dynamically-sized buffer available.  As Cubbi points out, UDP datagrams have a smallish maximum size anyway, so just make your buffer as large as the largest valid message in your system and be done with it.

Comment: `boost::asio::buffer` is a general ASyncronous Input/Output buffer, and is not only used for UDP.

Comment: Sure.  And in general it does not make sense to have a dynamic one.  Neither for your application nor for TCP nor any other protocol which eventually calls the low-level C routines to do their work, because it will only lead to inefficient memory copying, which anathema in C++ and in Boost.