# How do I assign a string to boost beast multi_buffer?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have found many examples showing how to copy the contents of a boost::beast::multi_buffer to a string, but how do I assign the contents of a string to a multi_buffer that has previously been created in a class instance?

If I have the example declarations in my class:

```
private:
    boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ws_;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
```

how do I assign a string to buffer_ before using it in a call to:

```
ws_.async_write(buffer_.data(), boost::asio::bind_executor(strand_,
    std::bind(&CNXG_session::on_write,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `boost::asio::buffer_copy` after [`prepare`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__basic_multi_buffer/prepare.html):

```
size_t n = buffer_copy(b.prepare(contents.size()), boost::asio::buffer(contents));
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82ac138746af482c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>

using boost::beast::multi_buffer;

void dump_buffer(std::ostream& os, multi_buffer const& mb) {
    os << mb.size() << " (" << mb.capacity() << ") "
       << "'" << boost::beast::buffers(mb.data()) << "'\n";
}

int main() {
    boost::beast::multi_buffer b;
    dump_buffer(std::cout << "before: ", b);

    std::string const contents = "Hello world";

    size_t n = buffer_copy(b.prepare(contents.size()), boost::asio::buffer(contents));
    b.commit(n);

    dump_buffer(std::cout << "after: ", b);
}
```

Prints

```
before: 0 (0) ''
after: 11 (512) 'Hello world'
```

---

Note: perhaps you'll be interested in a new buffer facility in Boost asio 1.66.0: `dynamic_buffer` ([Dynamically sized boost::asio::buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930738/dynamically-sized-boostasiobuffer/49245315#49245315))

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the `boost::beast::ostream` function to turn a DynamicBuffer into a `std::ostream` you can write to:

```
boost::beast::multi_buffer b;
boost::beast::ostream(b) << "Hello, world!\n";
```